# fft_fftn(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not list

Tags: fft, huggingface-transformers, vision

I am a student who doesn't having much experience in using PyTorch. I'm having a lot of trouble with my image. I want to use the Fourier transform in my image and I would training the image with vision transformer. But when I try to apply the Fourier transform in my image I an error was reported.
This is my code

```
import torch
import torch.fft as fft
from transformers import ViTModel, ViTFeatureExtractor, Trainer, TrainingArguments

# Load pre-trained Vision Transformer model and feature extractor
model = ViTModel.from_pretrained('google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k')
feature_extractor = ViTFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained('google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k')
```

```
# Function to apply Fourier Transform to an image
def apply_fourier_transform(image):
    image_tensor = feature_extractor(images=image)['pixel_values']
    image_fft = fft.fftn(image_tensor)
    my_tensor = torch.tensor(image_tensor)
    return image_fft
```

```
# Apply Fourier Transform to each image in the dataset
dataset = ds.map(lambda example: {'image': apply_fourier_transform(example['image'])})
```

And I got this [error report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZeoz.png)

How to solve this error?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)